# How to tint single NavigationView MenuItem icon?

Tags: android, navigationview

I have a NavigationView with selectors set for both the icon tint and the text color. It looks as follows.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_drawer_list_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_drawer_list_selector" />
```

I have several menu items displayed in this NavigationView. I want to have one of them tinted differently. I can access the item as such:

```
Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem noAdsItem = navMenu.findItem(R.id.item_navigation_purchase_no_ads);
```

I have tried all the following approaches.

1. setColorFilter()

```
noAdsItem.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

2. Wrapping the drawable and setting the tint

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_no_ads);

Drawable drawable = noAdsItem.getIcon();
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.content_brand));
```

3. Mutating the drawable and setting the tint

```
drawable.mutate();
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.content_brand), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.content_brand));
```

I have tried using a colored icon as a resource; it is overridden by the selector. I have tried removing the itemIconTint selector and tinting the icon then programmatically. All of these attempts were unsuccessful.

I know it is possible to, for example, color the text. I have used the SpannableString approach, and it worked.

```
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle().toString());
spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(spanString);
```

I am using Android Pie on a Pixel 3XL. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.